# can't use git for downloading from a non github repository

Tags: git, archlinux

so when I use

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/paru.git
```

or all the other repos
paru-bin.git
paru-git.git

git leaves this message

```
fatal: unable to acces `https://aur.archlinux.org/paru.git/' : Could not resolve host: aur.archlinux.org
```

it doesn't works from a newly installed arch linux. I guess it has something to do with git because when I try to do it from my main machine which also has arch linux it works perfectly. I have been looking for an answer for days but could't find one

also of course I have connection to the internet and I tried disabling the proxies like it says in this answer
but the strange think is that it works for github repos but not for this aur repos.

Comment: I Hope [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20370294/4672474) answer will help you!

Comment: The first thing to do with any network issue is to simplify it so as to find the root cause. Is *anything* (`nslookup`, `dig`, `ping`, etc) able to resolve `aur.archlinux.org`? Is the resolver set up correctly in the first place? If not, that's the problem. It's very likely *not* Git itself.