# AWS Elasticbeanstalk unable to push to server - Certificate expired

Tags: git, amazon-web-services

I have been pushing to an AWS Elasticbeanstalk ,

Just yesterday, whenever I run the command

```
git aws.push
```

I get the following error:

```
Pushing to environment
fatal: unable to access
SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
```

The url its going to is: git.elasticbeanstalk.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Is there something I need to do from powershell to update the certificate so git recognises it?

Comment: Charlie, were you ever able to resolve this? If so, it would be great if you could add an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Stealing the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377703/syncing-with-github); it's probably an issue with the `http.sslcainfo` setting. To see the current value, enter the following at the command line:

```
git config --system --get http.sslcainfo
```

This is the path of the CA certificate that's used by git when accessing a repo over a secure connection (note that the path is relative to the git root installation folder). I'm using GitHub for Windows on my PC and it was configured to use the following certificate:

```
/bin/curl-ca-bundle-ghfw.crt
```

In my case, for some reason, this certificate had expired. I re-configured it to point to a different certificate (in the same folder) using the following command:

```
git config --system http.sslcainfo /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Where did you get the different certificate from?

Comment: Both certificates files were under the `/bin` folder for the GitHub install. At the moment, my path to the bin folder is `C:\Users\camel\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\bin`