# How to avoid username while doing git commit

Tags: command-line, github, commit

I have set user name and email by following these commands

```
$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"
$ git config --global user.email "your@email.address"
```

but whenever i commit the changes it asks for username always, I don't want to enter it always since it is set already.

The command should only ask for password not the user.

How to do this in git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is duplicate to : [Git asks for username everytime I push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403407/git-asks-for-username-everytime-i-push)

But better: use ssh instead of https

take a look here: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys