# Store token when using Github + HTTPS + two-factor authentication

Tags: git, authentication, github

I've `git clone` a repo from Github using the HTTPS remote url as [recommended by Github](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/).

I've also set up two-factor authentication in my Github account ([also recommended](https://help.github.com/articles/about-two-factor-authentication/)), which means I had to [generate a token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/) to be able to push changes to my repo.

Now, every time I attempt to push `git` asks for my Username and Password.

This has been addressed a number of times here, and the consensus both in StackOverflow ([Git asks for username everytime I push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403407/git-asks-for-username-everytime-i-push#comment45012544_17979600), [How secure is storing password with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28104581/1391441)) and [Github](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/) seems to be: don't use `git config credential.helper store` to remember your token, use `git config --global credential.helper cache` instead.

According to Github, I can set up a time to cache my token with:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```

Since the process of obtaining a new token is [rather cumbersome](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/),  I want to store it for quite some time.

This is the point where I'm not sure I'm using the tool appropriately. Would it be ok if I set my token to be cached for say a month?

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=2592000'
```

This seems to me somewhat a convoluted way to go about this. Is this the way this should be done or am I simply doing things wrong?

Comment: You should use private key authentication instead.

Comment: But that would imply using SSH right? So I shouldn't use HTTPS as recommended by Github?

Comment: GitHub only recommends HTTPS because it works in more cases (some networks use firewalls that prevent cloning over SSH, but this is rare for HTTPS).