# Why TFS with GIT is not working from command line?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, active-directory

I want to use the git command line tools with the Microsoft Team Foundation Server Git repositories.

But every time I want to access to remote repos the authentication fails. And of course I am using Active Directory (this is a TFS server). The git repo management works perfectly from Visual Studio. (even push, sync, clone, etc).

```
Cloning into 'blabla'
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://server:8080/tfs/BlaCollection/_git/blabla/'
```

I have intented using this patters and always fail.

- DOMAIN\username
- username@domainforest

Anyone has get connected using command line tools to a TFS with git server?
In my company we use tokens to log on Windows, may be the reason?

Comment: What's the version of the Git you use? Can you install the latest Git and then try again?

Comment: I have tested with lastest: 2.9.0-windows1. But is the same thing.

Comment: Install GCM and then try again: https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally a collegue hit the solution and I will post it here:

Use the command:

```
git config --global credential.http://[tfs_server].integrated true
```

Of course, replace `[tfs_server]` with your own TFS server host name.

When Credential Manager asks for credentials just leave blanks and press OK. (I this way authentication will be performed using Kerberos).

Check  here for more information https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows#q-i-thought-microsoft-was-maintaining-this-why-does-the-gcm-not-work-as-expected-with-tfs

Comment: I tried to follow your tip but without success. Each time I start a clone following error appears:
Cloning into 'BETR_WP%20Route'...
Fatal: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException encountered.
Details: tokenSecretStore can't be null
Fatal: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException encountered.  Details:
tokenSecretStore can't be null
Username for 'http://tfsapp1:8080':

Comment: thx ! Its okey for me. This one is interesting but necessary! "When Credential Manager asks for credentials just leave blanks and press OK."

Answer (score 43):

Windows Credentials -> Generic Credentials

Then add a new item with "git:" in front of the http:// i.e.:

git:http://Example.com

add domain\user as user,
and password

Comment: This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This really helped me in windows 10.

Comment: Added just "Example.com" without prefix, worked too.

Answer (score 22):

I did two things to make it work. Try below.

1. Update your git to the latest version.
2. Open Windows Credential Manager by typing the same in Windows Search and remove the  git credentials in the generic credentials as shown below
   [image]

Comment: This worked! Fighting TFS + Git on Windows 10, and this worked! Thank you!

Comment: I changed the password and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For myself, I went to Control Panel > Credential Manager > Windows Credentials.

I tried to delete only the Generic Credentials with *git:* in front of them, but the git commands still didn't work.

After I deleted the Windows Credentials for the TFS server, then the git commands started to work.

Answer (score 2):

> No matter, how your company use to log on windows, you just need the account which login in the TFS. You can find the account info in Windows-Control Panel- Credential Manager
>
>
> by [PatrickLu-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5391065/patricklu-msft)

This is what did it for me. I just opened the Windows Credential Manager as stated above and edited the credentials because some how it was stuck to my previous password.

Answer (score 2):

My solution

Open Control Panel > Credential Manager > Windows Credentials.

Under Generic Credentials -> Add a generic credential

Inter network address: git:https://tfs.[google].com

admin:

password:

Replace google with the domain of your company. Put your EID or credentials to log into TFS.

Answer (score 1):

If you face this error after changing password for TFS,

Go to Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager

Under the Windows Credentials, 
Modify the password for the specific Internet or network address.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change your AD password recently ?

- If so, (or not lol), Go to Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager > Windows Credentials.
- Locate entries starting with git:http...
- Either Remove that/those entry, or edit the password to the new one.  Click on the Down Arrow and you see info about that entry, including the Remove/Edit links

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this issue before in SourceTree and solved using using the below solution

In Windows

- Open Control Panel > Credential Manager > Windows Credentials.

or
just search `Windows Credentials` in windows search.

Under Generic Credentials -> Add a generic credential

And fill these data

- Internet or network address: `tfs url` ex: https://tfs.test.com
- username:
- password:

Replace test with the domain of your company. Put your EID or credentials to log into TFS.

And in SourceTree

- From Tools> Options> Git> Disable SSL certificate validation

Answer (score 0):

For me it was that a proxy had been set in config. `>git config --global --unset http.proxy` made it work. Running a VM Windows Server 20196 and TFS2015 usind Kerberos (Windows Authentication).

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove your git credentials from Windows Control Panel (as what everyone is suggesting)
2. If cmd still  not prompting you for reentering of git credentials. e.g

> fatal: Authentication failed for ....

You may try to uninstall your git-windows and choose the 'None' option. To avoid using a credentials helper.

[Screenshot page for None Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxnL9.png)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the Authentication  `--username` and `--password` parameters with the command directly such as:

```
git tfs clone http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection $/Project1 -u=Domain\username -p=xxx
```

> -u, --username=VALUE     stands for  TFS username
>   -p, --password=VALUE        stands for  TFS password

No matter, how your company use to log on windows, you just need the account which login in the TFS. You can find the account info in `Windows-Control Panel- Credential Manager`

---

Visual Studio store credentials in the Windows Credential Manager, which is compatible with the [Git Credential Winstore](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows). 
If you install Git Credential Winstore, it should permanently authenticating with Git repositories, you can also give this tool a try.

Comment: No. I am not using Visual Studio Online. And the blog post have the wrong title

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, please see my update. Did you use the -u -p in the Git command directly? And no matter how your company use to log on windows, you just need the account which login in the TFS. You can find the account info in `Windows-Control Panel- Credential Manager`

Comment: thanks for you help, I tried what you said but I get `git: 'tfs' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`  My git client do not have any tfs option

Comment: I checked this, but this is intented for TFS collections appear as local bare git repo. My remote is a TFS-with-GIT repository and my local is git too, but the remote have Windows authentication. Thats my issue.