# Run Git commands on TFS 2015 build steps was failed

Tags: git, tfs, oauth, tfs-2015

I try to follow [these steps](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/scripts/git-commands) to add some git commands on TFS 2015 (Update 3) build steps.

For testing, I tried 'git ls-files', that worked.

And then I tried 'git pull'.

It would show:

```
2017-02-09T03:23:36.7164903Z git pull
2017-02-09T03:23:36.7164903Z Error message highlight pattern:  
2017-02-09T03:23:36.7164903Z Warning message highlight pattern: 
2017-02-09T03:23:36.9660887Z bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address 
2017-02-09T03:23:36.9660887Z error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
2017-02-09T03:23:36.9660887Z fatal: could not read Username for 'http://htwb0228:8080': Invalid argument
```

However, Git totally worked well on '_work' folder of TFS server via the local operation.

I already tried many solutions. For me, they didn't work.

I tried to use the [Git Build Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ioz.vsts-git-build-tasks), it was still failed.

```
2017-02-09T01:53:41.3965148Z git pull
2017-02-09T01:53:41.3965148Z Error message highlight pattern: 
2017-02-09T01:53:41.3965148Z Warning message highlight pattern: 
2017-02-09T01:53:42.4729079Z fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://OAuth:********@htwb0228:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/KKKKK/_git/PPPP/'
```

For this issue, I referred [this page](http://cnblogs.nbhczl.com/zjoch/p/5833987.html) to add two variables (VSO_GIT_USERNAME & VSO_GIT_PASSWORD) for building scripts. It still didn't work.

I upgraded Git to 2.11.1 and installed [GCMW](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) on TFS server.

Moreover, by referring [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736232/why-tfs-with-git-is-not-working-from-command-line), I also typed these commands on TFS server.

```
git config --global credential.http://htwb0228:8080.integrated true
git config --global credential.http://htwb0228.integrated true
git config --global credential.htwb0228.integrated true
git config --global credential.integrated true
```

It still didn't work.

Is there any other suggestion? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use command below will work:

```
git pull http://username:password@tfsserver:8080/tfs/teamprojectCollection/_git/GitProject/
```

Check the screenshot below:

[image]

For the password, you can add a variable and keep it secret.

[image]

Comment: That is a very long way round to solve a very simple problem that has an OOB solution provided by the Build Team.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to save a username and password. All you need to do is enable the "Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token" and your build tasks will be able to call back to TFS/VSTS using the build in authentication.

[image]

Although this screenshot is from VSTS the option also exists in TFS and has the same name.

[image]

Once it has been enabled you can call back to your git repo, or any other TFS resolved without additional authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I described, ''I try to follow [these steps](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/scripts/git-commands) to add...". So I already "Allow scripts to access OAuth token". That doesn't work for me. Maybe I made something wrong on my TFS server.