# my old username is still in use

Tags: git, github

I have changed my user and email for git with those commands

```
git config --global user.name "maa"
git config user.email "maa@gmail.com"
```

I confirmed the change with

```
git config --global user.name
git config user.email
```

and it shows the right names. 
However when I push the old user name is used:

```
git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to maa/brain.git denied to old_user_name.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/maa/brain.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your local git config name/email have nothing to do with github users and their permissions. You'd have to change your username on Github too.

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: upvoting because there is no shame on not knowing things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `user.name` and `user.email` settings are only used for commit meta data.

As I can see you are using https transport, so the username is stored somehow. To my mind there are two options:

1. You are using `%HOME%/.netrc` (`%HOME%/_netrc` or `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\_netrc` on Windows)
2. Your username is included in the push-url (like `https://username@github.com/...`), here you need to update `.git/config`, e.g. by issuing `git remote set-url https://<newusername>@github.com/<newusername>/yourRepo`
3. You are using a git credential helper. Here it depends which one you use (and maybe which OS you use, [see for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31782500/3906760), [Mac OS X](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/)).

As a general rule you can try the following on the CLI (based on [2](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/)), where you replace `$credentialhelper` with your credential-helper (you can find it using `git config credential.helper`, for Mac OS X it is likely `osxkeychain` on Windows it might be `wincred` or `manager`):

```
$ git credential-$credentialhelper erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
[Press Return]
```

Comment: 1 liner for mac: `git credential-$(git config credential.helper) erase`

Answer (score 3):

Locally:

```
git config credential.username 'new_username'
```

Globally:

```
git config --global credential.username  'new_username'
```