# How to get command line to re-prompt for username/password for github when cloning repository

Tags: git, github

I am new to using github, and the professor of a class that I am in is storing the source code and assignment information in a repository that I need to clone with the following command `git clone https://github etc. etc.`

I incorrectly entered my username and password for Github the first time I was prompted, and now I'm stuck with failed authentications like `remote: Invalid username or password fatal: Authentication failed` because it won't reprompt me. Any insight into this issue? Some things online made it seem that it could be fixed by fiddling with a thing called credential.helper, but didn't make it clear how that would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on Windows, see "[How do I sign out in the Git Bash console on Windows?](http://git%20credential-manager%20reject%20%3Curl%3E)"

```
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com" | git credential-manager reject 
# or
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com" | git credential-manager erase
```

If you are on Mac, see "[Updating credentials from the OSX Keychain](https://help.github.com/en/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain)"

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39944557/6309), but replacing "`erase`" with "`delete`" or "`erase`".

Comment: On Windows, the command appeared to hang. When I pressed <Enter> there was a message with "InvalidOperationException" but the command did succeed in resetting the credentials for that server. I suspect my credential-manager docs aren't right.

Comment: @PeterL True. I have restored the proper syntax in a Git for Windows bash shell.