# SSH into VM and run "git pull" using Paramiko - Python

Tags: python, git, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to SSH into my VM and did perform a `git pull`

- the SSH seems to be working fine
- the git pull seem to be executed
- but when I provide password, it doesn't seem to take it
- Am I missing something ?

---

I have

```
import paramiko
import time
import sys
import os
import pdb

# Note
# sudo pip install --user paramiko
ip = "111.111.111.111"
un = "root"
pw = "abc"

def ssh_con (ip, un, pw):
    global ssh
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip, username=un, password=pw)

def cmd_io (command):
    global ssh_cmd
    ssh_cmd.send("%s \n" %command)
    time.sleep(1)
    output = ssh_cmd.recv(10000).decode("utf-8")
    print (output)

ssh_con(ip,un,pw)
ssh_cmd = ssh.invoke_shell()
print ("SSH CONNECTION ESTABLISHED TO %s" % ip)
cmd_io("git pull")
time.sleep(2)
cmd_io(pw)
```

---

I kept getting

```
git pull 
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa': 

Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Comment: First create a `credential.helper` like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403407/git-asks-for-username-everytime-i-push

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your SSH Rsa Key pair  has been setup up with a pass phrase for root on 111.111.111.111. You can recreate the ssh rsa key with:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

and just leave pass phrase blank.

Comment: Semantics, but the pass phrase is not for `111.111.111.111`, but for the private key on the local host.  And if you recreate the ssh keys, the remote systems will need to know the new public key.