# Git clone fatal error, user credentials are correct

Tags: git, authentication

so I'm trying to clone a git repository but it keeps throwing an error about a failed authentication..

Here is the error:

```
$ git clone https://url...
Cloning into 'repo'...
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://url...'
```

I've checked my configs and the username and password for the repositry are correct but somehow the clone doesn't work.

Any tips on what I can do right now?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question directly, but consider using ssh for git connections.

Comment: Can you explain how I do that please? Im quite new to git..

Comment: use `git clone ssh://...´. A introduction regarding VSTS git authentification you'll find at https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/vsts/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=vsts

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/ explains how to use ssh keys and github, but the approach works with other repo hosting services as well.

Comment: Okay i've tried that now but it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: You might also look over the answers from [question 11403407](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403407/git-asks-for-username-every-time-i-push?rq=1) which has some more ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Answers from [question 11403407](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403407/git-asks-for-username-every-time-i-push?rq=1) fixed the issue.

The Code that worked for me looks like this:

```
git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

The `--system` was important here since `--global` didn't work.

Thanks for the help guys, especially [@Todd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/384724/todd)! :)

Comment: For anyone who doesn't have perms to write to system config, putting `[credential] helper =` with no value after the `=` in your global config has the same effect