# How can I make autofill username requested in linux shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell

I have `.sh` script that uses git for a pull request. While running it I always get requested for username and password. So how to make autofill for username?

`pull.sh` contents:

```
cd /home/test/project

git pull
```

Comment: Hi Rustam, please share the username and password fields you get so I can help you with it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403407/git-asks-for-username-every-time-i-push (read all answers)

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [git-credential-cache](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache). It will prompt for credentials just the first time.

To avoid username/password at alI I would suggest to use Ssh and Ssh keys for authentication (e.g: [in gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/)).

Comment: If the repository is being accessed using the HTTP or HTTPS protocol (can be verified by running `git remote -v`), one can use the `~/.netrc` file to store the credentials (see [this](https://gist.github.com/technoweenie/1072829) or [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/The-_002enetrc-file.html) for a formal manual page). The password is stored **in clear text** so _this file must have tight permissions set_ — such as `0600`.

Comment: Still, I personally find the Git credentials cache to be the best solution out there.

Answer (score -1):

Install `expect` tool in your system

Do following Stuff in your bash file

```
*#!/usr/bin/expect -f*

cd /home/test/project
git pull
expect "sername"
send your_username
send "\r"
expect "assword"
send {your_password}
send "\r"
interact
```

Hope it works !

Answer (score -1):

You can use expect script to interact with git to do git pull and then authentication.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn git pull
expect "username: " # write the keyword you get as prompt for entering username 
send "your_username\r"
# remove the below 2 lines if you do not want script to interact for password. 
expect "password: " # write the keyword you get as prompt for entering password 
send "your_password\r"
interact
```

if you don't want to store password, you can enter it as an argument. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set my_password [lindex $argv 0] 
spawn git pull
expect "username: " # write the keyword you get as prompt for entering username 
send "your_username\r"
expect "password: " # write the keyword you get as prompt for entering password 
send "${my_password}\r"
interact
```

Run this script as `./myScript.sh <password>` .