# GIT - Keeps asking username even after global storage

Tags: git

I have saved my username globally in GIT when I check by using `git config --global user.name` command, it shows me correct username but it still keeps me asking username every time when I push or commit the code.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `user.name` is not a ‘username’, but your full name that goes before the `<>` in your full e-mail address (always set both `user.name` and `user.email`!).

Answer (score 2):

Asking for your username when pushing is about authentication, not commit authorship.

Regarding authentication (credentials, username/password provided to a remote Git repository hosting service), you need to check your [`git config credential.helper`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials): that setting can setup a cache, avoiding to request your credentials every time you are pushing.

As the [OP Pribhav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8186857/pribhav) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56395529/git-keeps-asking-username-even-after-global-storage/56395582?noredirect=1#comment99390136_56395582), you can as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11407483/6309), embed the username in the URL (`https://username@site/...`).
Nut the `credential.helper` is still needed to avoid asking for your password.

Comment: Unless it is an SSH URL, but if it uses git@, it should not require your username.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response finally, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403407/git-asks-for-username-every-time-i-push#answer-11407483 it saved my time

Comment: Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.