# Git keeps asking for my user.name and user.mail despite global storage (ssh key)

Tags: git

When I try to commit to a local `git`, it keeps asking me to set up a `user.mail` and `user.name`, despite them being setup correctly both locally and globally.

I seem to have the same problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56395529/19918448).
The solution proposed (setting `url = "https://username@website.com/git_name"` in `.git/config`) is both not working and not satisfying (I want to keep using SSH).

Is this a bug ?
I am running git version 2.32.1 (Apple Git-133) on a new Macbook Pro with a M1 Pro cpu.
Both my windows and WSL installation have no problem like this whatsoever.

Comment: Your `user.name` and `user.email` settings have nothing to do with authentication (and so nothing to do with the url). It sounds like you haven't set `user.name` and `user.email` globally in your git configuration. Git should be providing you with instructions on how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the [solution I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56395582/6309) was for an HTTPS URL, not an SSH one.

Meaning `url = "https://username@website.com/git_name"`, not `url = "username@website.com/git_name"`.

Second, if you get an error on `git commit`, it has nothing to do with the git remote `origin` URL.

Check what is configured with:

```
git config -l --show-origin --show-scope
```

The [OP Magyar_57](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19918448/magyar-57) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73603053/git-keeps-asking-for-my-user-name-and-user-mail-despite-global-storage-ssh-key/73605749#comment129983704_73605749):

> ```
>  global file:/Users/me/.gitconfig user.name=myusername 
>  global file:/Users/me/.gitconfig user.mail=mymail@mail.com
> ```

That is the error:
You need to set `email`, not `mail`:

```
git config --global user.email mymail@mail.com
                        ^^^
```

Comment: I corrected the url mistake in my post. I checked what you asked me to and I got:
```
me@pc ~ % git config -l --show-origin --show-scope
unknown file:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/gitconfig    credential.helper=osxkeychain
global  file:/Users/me/.gitconfig     user.name=myusername
global  file:/Users/me/.gitconfig     user.mail=mymail@mail.com
```
I dont understand what Xcode have to do with github configuration here, but I guess it might be causing some issues

Comment: @Magyar_57 I have edited the answer to address your configuration error.