# Git skip username prompt

Tags: git

I've set `user.name` *and* `user.email` in the config when `user.name` didn't work, but I am still prompted for my username every time I push/pull from remote.

```
$ git config user.name 'myemail@example.com'
$ git config user.email 'myemail@example.com'
$ git pull
Username for 'https://example.com':
```

How can I skip that prompt?

I still want to be forced to enter a password every time.

Comment: @Ben your answer on that question is the same as bk2204's answer on this one. I will probably accept bk2204's answer once I confirm it. I didn't find that question when I was searching for an answer before I posted my question, it's the same question. Unfortunately most of the answers on it aren't useful for me. It probably still counts as a duplicate though.

Answer (score 3):

`user.name` and `user.email` have nothing to do with authentication.  They represent the values that should be stored in your commits; that is, your name and email address as stored in the author and committer fields and as viewed in `git log`.

`user.name` should be your personal name; that is, some form of the name that other humans call you by.

For authentication, you can either use a username in the URL, such as `https://myemail%40example.com@example.com/owner/repo.git`, or you can run `git config credential.https://example.com/.username myemail@example.com`.  Note that if you put the value in the URL, you need to percent-encode any relevant characters, as I've demonstrated.

Comment: If the git repository is located at `https://example.com/path/to/repo.git`, do I specify that whole URL in the config

Comment: You would edit `.git/config` to adjust the repository URL to include the `username@` portion as mentioned.

Comment: I mean, does the config store the username per-domain or per-repository. Your example command is: `git config credential.https://example.com/.username myemail@example.com`, but should it be `git config credential.https://example.com/path/to/repo.git.username myemail@example.com` for the remote at `https://example.com/path/to/repo.git` ?

Comment: Unless you have a good reason, use just the portion of the URL with the hostname, although either is acceptable.  See `gitcredential(7)` for more details.

Comment: Why is the url method recommended?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

for more information and settings check this link: 
[freecodecamp.org](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-fix-git-always-asking-for-user-credentials/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's going to store the password as well, which the OP said they didn't want.

Comment: you are right :)

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the `--global` flag to save that in in your global git config. To also cache your username for `git push`, see [Git asks for username every time I push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403407/git-asks-for-username-every-time-i-push)