# Github grayed out and changed name to lowercase, commits are no longer counted

Tags: linux, github

[image]

Pretty much what the image shows. I don't have my credentials stored on my PC, I type them in each time. The machine and credentials are identical between all commits, and I'm the only person allowed to work on that project anyways ...

Comment: Does `git config user.name` or `git config user.email` print something?

Comment: @vkozyrev "I don't have my credentials stored on my PC", "I type them in each time". They should be empty right ? It does always ask me on a push what my username and pass are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the user name and email in your PC as below, you will not have to type them in each time

```
 git config --global user.email "you@example.com"                                                                        
 git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Comment: Already set my email and pass by @vkozyrev suggestion. Still have to type em in :)

Comment: your PC is linux or windows?

Comment: Linux (and more text so i can post this answer)

Comment: Have you tried any of these [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403407/git-asks-for-username-every-time-i-push)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't think that I needed to save user.email and user.name if git asked each time for the email / pass anyways. Saving them made the issue go away