# How do I fix this error "remote: Invalid username or password." in git-bash terminal?

Tags: git, git-bash

When I try to push the code using **git push** in the `git-bash` terminal I get the `remote: Invalid username or password.`, but when try pushing the code using `Visual studio code` or `IntelliJ`, it prompts me to enter username and password. After entering the u/n and password, it gets successfully pushed. How do I fix this in git-bash? The git-bash doesn't prompt me to enter username and password.

Below is the command:

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin fix_sonar
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.dhdjfjfn.com/jdjdjdjd/nvbcf.git/'
```

Comment: May be git config problem . take a look https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/setting-your-username-in-git

Comment: Check if this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403407/git-asks-for-username-every-time-i-push

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes git caches credentials even if you mistyped try "cmdkey delet" and the URL of your repository. Then you should also be asked for your login data on the bash.