# Can bazaar remember the password using protocol https+webdav?

Tags: bazaar

For any push/pull operation on a https+webdav Bazaar repository, bzr asks for my password. Can bazaar remember the password using https+webdav without putting it in the repo URL (similarly to [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233590/is-there-a-way-to-make-git-remember-the-password-for-webdav-remotes))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[authentication.conf](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.5/en/user-reference/authentication-help.html) (see also [the developer documentation](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/developers/authentication-ring.html)) allows you to configure a password for a particular host.

authentication.conf looks like this:

```
[webdav.foo.fr]
scheme=https # https even if the repo URL is https+webdav
host=webdav.foo.fr
user=monperrus
password=sdfozaekjh
```

The password may also be specified in netrc:

```
[webdav.foo.fr]
scheme=https
host=webdav.foo.fr
user=monperrus
password_encoding=netrc
```